# Google Play developer console - nexus 7 is supported but cannot install apk

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, nexus-7

I have published my first camera app, and in developer console currently there are 4282 supported devices and 0 excluded.

Three Nexus 7 models are listed in the supported list (1.Google Nexus 7 - flo, 2.Google Nexus 7 - deb and 3.Nexus 7), however i cannot install the apk on my Nexus 7 (2012) through Google Play saying it's not compatible. (i use to test my app on that device, it runs perfectly).

I know my manifest should include

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

to be compatible with Nexus 7, but why does it appear in the supported list?

[Using the device availability dialog document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en) states:

> Device Availability provides a dynamic list of compatible devices
>   based upon your manifest settings

so my Nexus 7 should not be listed!

Do i miss something?

**EDIT**

here's manifest permissions and features:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: show your manifest.xml please, especially the features/permissions section.

Comment: @robin manifest permissions and features added, i know i should set required="false" on camera features, but i wouldn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

to the manifest file (although i wouldn't, because actually camera is required), 56 devices were added to the supported devices list, included two more  Nexus 7, now they are:

```
GoogleNexus 7– grouper
Nexus 7
GoogleNexus 7– tilapia
GoogleNexus 7– deb
GoogleNexus 7– flo
```

I deduce that deb and flo are the new ones, with back camera, and old ones (v2012) are grouper and tilapia, i don't know about the ones labeled "Nexus 7" only.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, some Nexus 7 devices do not need any user permission for Camera or WiFi, but has to be used the uses feature instead.

For example, use these

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your G7 has camera? If not, it is correct that you cannot see it from GooglePlayStore on your G7  (since you have set require camera = true).

And another check point,  might mean you should have a GPS.

Comment: My Nexus 7 has only front camera. As i wrote, i know i should use camera require="false", the question is why i see it in the supported device list.